# build for different targets conditionally

Tags: android

I have been building for API 14 so far. I'm trying to get ready now, so I downloaded and specified API 7 as my target. I have some compilation errors because a few api's I was using in API14 aren't available in API7.

I am wondering how I could put them in conditionals. Something on the lines of:

```
if (API_14)
{
    if (mTextEdit.isEmpty()) {
        // Do Something
    }
} else if (API_7){
    if (mTextEdit.matches("")) {
        // Do the same thing
    }
}
```

This has to be a compile time conditional switch because otherwise my code won't even compile.

I've heard before that pre-processors are not supported in Java, so I welcome suggestions on how best to manage my source which I'm targeting for multiple versions.

**Edit:**
I also am running into trouble with my state list drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

Of course, hold_orange_dark isn't available in API7. I'd like to be able to manage those as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do ifs, or you'll have a crash on older devices.

You have to use Java Reflection to use methods from more recent APIs conditionally.

An example: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java-reflection/

Answer (score 0):

For your resources you can [specify different directories](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) for different platform versions. So you'd make a Values-v14 directory to have a copy of any resources that use anything from that API version and a Values directory so Values would be used by default and Values-v14 would only be used if the device was version 14.

As for doing it programmatically, you could try a Try-Catch like so-

```
try {
      //Insert ICS stuff here
    } catch(NoSuchMethodError e){
    }
```

Or you could try this-

```
public static boolean isHoneycomb() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
}
```